# Substitute text if number inferior to value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dataset, mutate

I have a dataset like this

```
structure(list(value = c(2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 12)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to create a new column "X" at this condition: if value <5, then I for that row I want it to display "<5" as a string, if >=5 then the row in the new column should be equal to "value".
Something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqusL.png)
I tried using mutate and case when... I write the following code:

```
mutate(X = case_when(value < 5 ~ "<5"))
```

However I don't know how to continue.. I don't know what to write in order to copy the number from "Value" if >=5

Comment: If you only have two conditions, you can use `df %>% mutate(X = if_else(value < 5, "< 5", as.character(value)))`. If you want to stick with `case_when`, the code should be `df %>% mutate(X = case_when(value < 5 ~ "< 5", value >= 5 ~ as.character(value)))`

Comment: @benson23 Thank you! I didn't know the function "as.character"! That is what I was looking for!

Comment: @benson23 does as.character convert the value from "Value" to string? I want them to be numeric

Comment: A dataframe column cannot have two classes of values. The inclusion of "<" symbol will make the data type "character", therefore your `value` must also be "character" to be in the same column